# Making query return 404 when using cache

Tags: laravel

In my controller I have

```php
public function single($slug)
    {
        return view('post.single', [
            'country' => $this-> getPostBySlugCached($slug),
        ]);
    }
```

And in a cache trait:

```php
private function getPostBySlugCached(string $slug)
    {
        return Cache::tags(['post'])->remember('post:slug:'.$slug, CacheRemember::FOUR_WEEKS, function () use ($slug) {
            return Post::where('slug', $slug)
                ->firstOrFail();
        });
    }
```

But what happens if I put in a slug that doesn't exit, I don't get a 404 which is what I would expect given I'm using `firstOrFail()`. Instead I get errors because `$post` in the blade view is `null`. Is that because `Cache::remember` returns `null`? If so, how can I achieve so that it will return a 404?

Answer (score 0):

small change to your controller

```
    public function single($slug)
    { 
        $country = $this-> getPostBySlugCached($slug);

        abort_if(!$country,404);

        return view('post.single', compact('country');
    }
```